# Call an object that was created in a function from outside that function

Tags: python, class

Use case is simple: I create an object from a class in Python. If I create that object outside of any function, I have no problem getting back any of the attributes.

But somehow if I happened to create that object inside a function, I cannot get it back anywhere.

This works:

```
class UserTest():
    def__init__(self,name,age,size):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.size=size

FirstUser=UserTest(name,age,size)

print(FirstUser.name,FirstUser.age,FirstUser.size)
```

But this does not:

```
class UserTest():
    def__init__(self,name,age,size):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.size=size

def createUser(name,age,size):
    FirstUser=Usertest(name,age,size)
    return FirstUser

createUser('Max',38,180)

print(FirstUser.name,FirstUser.age,FirstUser.size)
```

And I cannot figure why I cannot find the object I just created, even if I return the FirstUser object at the end of the function.
What am I missing?

Comment: You don't assign the value returned from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Any variable assignment changes the scope of the variable to the current code block.

This means, in your code the variable `FirstUser` is only known inside `createUser`.

To use `FirstUser` as a global variable, you could use the `global` keyword:

```
def createUser(name,age,size):
    global FirstUser
    FirstUser=UserTest(name,age,size)
    return FirstUser

createUser('Max',38,180)

print(FirstUser.name,FirstUser.age,FirstUser.size)
```

or even better: do not use global variables, but work with the return value:

```
def createUser(name,age,size):
    return UserTest(name,age,size)

FirstUser = createUser('Max',38,180)

print(FirstUser.name,FirstUser.age,FirstUser.size)
```

Comment: Thank you all. Apparently my question was immediately closed (which is too bad because I had a side question). Sorry, I did research, but I could not make any sense of it. I understand that you have to put a variable, even if temporary. But does that work the same way when you want ot update an existing attribute let's say INSIDE another function?

Comment: @Akadok You might want to start here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/476. That's about PHP, not Python, but the basics are very similar, in that you need to understand *scope* first. Then it'll make more sense that you must pass *values* into functions as parameters and *return values* from functions. (Note that the scoping rules are slightly different between PHP and Python, so only take away the general idea, not the specifics.)

Answer (score 0):

Object returned by `createUser('Max',38,180)` has to be assigned or cached into a reference variable which can then be used to call its members, like such
`user  = createUser('Max',38,180)`
then this reference variable  `user` can be used to call its members.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value from createUser is not assigned

*You also have some typos : missing spaces and case*

Input:

```
class UserTest():
    def __init__(self,name,age,size):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.size=size

def createUser(name,age,size):
    return UserTest(name,age,size)

## ANSWER CORE ##
firstUser = createUser('Max',38,180)

print(firstUser.name,firstUser.age,firstUser.size)
```

Output:

```
Max 38 180
```